# How to Synchronize SQL Server 2008 and SQLITE Database

Tags: android, asp.net, sqlite, sql-server-2008

I have a Website and a Mobile Application on which people register them. The problem here is that Website  using SQL server 2008 and my android application is using SQ-Lite. Is there any way that both my website and android application use the same database.

Comment: when you say synchronize, you mean to say put whatever in SQL server into your app's SQLite?

Comment: yes you got my question

Comment: Is there any way user1506104 ?

Comment: Yes there is a way. But I suggest just put the necessary info into to your SQLite, not all.

Comment: ok, Have you any links or suggestions to do that. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Thanks  user1506104

Answer (score 0):

Do not put all data into your SQLite DB. Just save data that are necessary for your app to work. For SQLite manipulation here is the doc: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html